# .gitignore file not ignoring .env.local or any other supposed private file

Tags: gitignore

I encountered this error because I once mistakenly committed `.env.local` before adding it to `.gitignore`. The answer to it below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're facing something similar and you use the Git GUI in VSCode, just follow these steps:

- Open your `.env.local` file or any file that's having this issue, copy the content to clipboard, and delete the file entirely.
- Open your `.gitignore` file and delete the line that removes that file.
- Commit your changes (not necessarily publish).
- Now create a new `.env.local` file (or the file you deleted earlier in your case.)
- Switch to your Source Control tab (where you see staged files), right click on this newly created file and add it to `.gitignore`

Now, it will be ignored for real.